# What is an efficient way to store georeferenced information for web services?

Tags: geolocation, scalability

I am specifically thinking about Ovi Maps or any other similar georeferenced web service. What is an efficient way to partition data so to scale properly? How do these services store data so to reduce the effort necessary to  lookup a street in a city of nation starting from a pair of coordinates? How do they also store the "shape" of geographical entities? P.S: This was an interview question.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGIS is a good reference/standard for location based entities/services: http://www.opengeospatial.org/

MySQL, the commonly used RDBMS has some geospatial support. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

I don't have experience of sharding/partitioning data like this but guess you could do so by country or by creating "tiles".

Comment: My question was explicitly about how to partition/shard data in an efficient way. Fixed dimension tiles won't do: what to do if a street spawns multiple tiles. I am asking this question because someone else asked me the same question during an interview and I wasn't able to come out with a satisfing answer. So I am mainly interested in the "algorithmic" point of view. I will take a look at your links and see if I can find some insight there.